# Display multiple values from file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I'm trying to display a checklist using React. So I'm loading a json file that looks something like this:
{
"todos":
[{"id":1,"todo":"Do something nice for someone I care about","completed":true,"userId":26},{"id":2,"todo":"Memorize the fifty states and their capitals","completed":false,"userId":48},{"id":3,"todo":"Watch a classic movie","completed":false,"userId":4}]
,"total":150,"skip":0,"limit":30
}
And I'm also using mui's checkboxes. So I want to display a checkbox and its "defaultChecked" should be on when "completed" is true.

I managed to load the json and display checkboxes, but I cant figure out how to display all of them.

Code:

```
import './App.css';
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import { Checkbox, FormControlLabel, FormGroup } from '@mui/material';

import data from './todo-list.json';

function App() {
  for(let i = 0; i < data.todos.length; i++) {
    if(data.todos[i].completed) {
      var checkbox = console.log(data.todos[i].id, data.todos[i].todo);
    }
    else {
      console.log(data.todos[i].id, data.todos[i].todo);
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <FormGroup>
          <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox defaultChecked />} label="Label" />
          <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox />} label="Label 2" />
        </FormGroup>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I managed to load the json and display checkboxes, but I cant figure out how to display all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map on your todos and render accordingly.

Your return should look like this.

```
 return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <FormGroup>
          {data.todos.map(todo => <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox checked={todo.completed} />} label={todo.todo} /> )}
        </FormGroup>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked, but for some reason when I click the checkboxes nothing happens.

Comment: If you need to control manually the value of the checkbox, you have to store the data within the state, and update it with an onChange event. Can you give me more context about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You can change the prop checked to defaultChecked and it should do it